# Template not showing in my Laravel 6.6 project with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I made the basic installation from Vue.JS in my Laravel project, this is my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "7.*",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

So I run this code that everyone does after installation **npm run install && npm run dev** for the mix from Laravel generate the files, every tutorial say that I must put this in the footer from my main file

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

And always say that the file doesn't exist, it is true because when I run this command from mix above, this simple make a js and a css folder in a new public folder, this is the right approach? because I don't see any tutorial that this command makes a public folder, see the image below:

[image]

So when I explicitly put this path:

```
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

My Vue.js is loaded and I see the default text from Vue.js in console, but when I put the template from this file **TesteFood.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>Testando VUE</h1>
</template>
```

Is not showing and I make this command too **npm run watch** no success.

Comment: do you run `composer require laravel/ui` then run `php artisan ui vue --auth` after that run `npm install && npm run dev` ?

Comment: It should be `asset('js/app.js')`. Your server should point to the `public` folder. Or are you opening your page like this `yousite.com/public` ?

Comment: Hi, adam I don't want my app opening to public folder, so a made the modification for my app to be in root folder, so I put the index.php from public folder on root and put the .htacess on root and is working fine. But this js is just a file generated by mix

Comment: @wavrik hi wavrik, please use "@adam" if you respond to me, so I get notified. Putting the `index.php` in the root is a very bad idea. Everyone will have access to your application files like `yourdomain.com/app/...` or  yourdomain.com/storage/app/..` etc. This is a huge security risk.

Comment: @wavrik and its in the docs that `css` and `js` belongs in the public folder: `https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/structure#the-public-directory`

Comment: Also, please provide the content of the file `public/js/app.js` and `resources/js/app.js` and the components in the resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `mix` helper function:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: i put this <script src="{{ mix('public/js/app.js') }}"></script> and this <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>, when i put with public i get this Unable to locate Mix file: /public/js/app.js, if don't i get this ERROR NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0):

I simply reinstall all my Laravel and install Vue.js and don't move the public folder and all is working fine.

Thank you all!

Comment: That's a really Cool Dude.!

Answer (score 0):

when you install the laravel 6, then run this command **composer require laravel/ui --dev** for integrating all vue js dependencies, then create your component and register that in app.js file like this :

**Vue.component('teste-food', require('./components/TesteFood.vue'));**
and then run **npm run dev** for compiling once the codes or **npm run watch** for compiling anythime you add some vue.js file or sass in your porject.
In this steps you should see your component.